# Viewing category pages without the word 'category' in URL

Tags: categories, pages, urls, rewrite-rules, seo

1. When I view a static page its url is like: `http://example.com/mybooks/`
2. When I view a category page its url is like: `http://example.com/category/books-ebooks/`

For SEO, I want some modification so that I do not have to use the word `category` to view category pages. e.g. it should be `http://example.com/books-ebooks/` instead of `http://example.com/category/books-ebooks/`

- How can this be done?
- I see a potential problem that WordPress engine may not be able to differentiate between pages and categories. Is it so?
- What are other pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically a duplicate of [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32561/using-same-slug-name-for-a-page-and-category/32589). It comes up a lot, and the remove category base functionality probably should be an option in WordPress to be honest.

Here was my answer from there:

> [No Category Base plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/) to remove the /category/ bit from the URL.

:)

---

If you have a page with the same name as a category, the page will be shown instead the category archive, but the URLs of posts won't be affected. At least, that used to be the case. I *think* I heard news of a recent change in the way WP calculates permalinks (for the better).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the "Worpdress SEO" plugin by Yoast. The plugin has an option that is able to fix the problem.
I'm not sure if this is required, but I entered also a "." (dot) into the category field from the perma links section.

Answer (score 0):

As the "No Category Base plugin" ("[wp-no-category-base](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/)" By iDope) suggested above "has been closed and is no longer available for download", I have tried "[No Category Base (WPML)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/)" By Marios Alexandrou and it works like a charm.